# i am using whatsapp chat export .i made it as a Json.i want store continuos messages as one message in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, node.js-fs

i have a whatsapp chat export i want to make the continuos messages as single message

`the messages are given below i want to make the continuos messages as single message`

`My NodeJs code`

`in this code i read the data from txt file a store in array`
`then the continuous messages should be placed under one object

`this program only joins two messages only not join the third one`

`how do i join the third element in the object`

```
const fs = require("fs");

var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("file.txt"));
var newData = [];
data.forEach((x, index, arr) => {
  if (index < arr.length - 1) {
    y = arr[index + 1];
    xkey = Object.keys(x);
    ykey = Object.keys(y);
    //console.log(xkey, ykey);
    if(xkey[0] == ykey[0]) {
      x = { [xkey]: x[xkey] + " " + y[ykey] };
      delete arr[index + 1];
    }
    newData.push(x);
  }
});
console.log(newData);
```

`This is the text file`

```
[
  { itachi: 'Sir' },{ itachi: 'hi ' },{ itachi: 'hello' },
  { Batman: 'hi' },Batman: 'how r u' },{ itachi: 'fine' },
 
]
```

`The Output i got`

```
[
  { itachi: 'Sir || hi' },{ itachi: 'hello' },
    { Batman: 'hi ||how r u' },{ itachi: 'fine' }, 
]
```

`The desired Output`

```
 { itachi: 'Sir || hi ||hello' },  { Batman: 'hi ||how r u' }, { itachi: 'fine' },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: I store the messages in the next element so that it will check the value again:

```
var data = [
  { itachi: 'Sir' },{ itachi: 'hi ' },{ itachi: 'hello' },
  { Batman: 'hi' },{Batman: 'how r u' },{ itachi: 'fine' },]


data.forEach((x, index, arr) => {
  if(index < arr.length - 1){
    y = arr[index + 1];
    xkey = Object.keys(x);
    ykey = Object.keys(y);
    //console.log(xkey, ykey);
    if(xkey[0] == ykey[0]) {
      x = { [xkey]: x[xkey] + " " + y[ykey] };
     arr[index]=""
     arr[index+1]=x
      
      
    }
    
  }
})
data=data.filter(x=>x!=="")
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check the final value. because the last value is skipped with the code `index < arr.length - 1`

```js
var data = [
  { itachi: 'Sir' },{ itachi: 'hi ' },{ itachi: 'hello' },
  { Batman: 'hi' },{Batman: 'how r u' },{ itachi: 'fine' },
]
var newData = [];
data.forEach((x, index, arr) => {
  if(index < arr.length - 1){
    y = arr[index + 1];
    xkey = Object.keys(x);
    ykey = Object.keys(y);
    //console.log(xkey, ykey);
    if(xkey[0] == ykey[0]) {
      x = { [xkey]: x[xkey] + " " + y[ykey] };
      delete arr[index + 1];
    }
    newData.push(x);
  }else{
    newData.push(x);
  }
});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: That's not working bro.. i check the value in if condition [index+1] so that would be arr.lenght-1..so found the answer thank you brother